# Como preencher uma coluna de um DF Pandas usando, como comparação, uma coluna específica entre este e outro DF?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tenho um dataframe Pandas, no qual preciso adicionar uma nova coluna chamada `codprojeto`. Para tal, criei esta nova coluna e inseri zeros, para que a mesma tenha o tipo `int64`, da seguinte maneira:

```
df['codprojeto'] = 0
```

Esta nova coluna deve ser alimentada com o `codprojeto` presente em outro dataframe. Esta coluna é do tipo `int64`, motivo pelo qual fiz o passo anterior.

Como comparação, estou usando a coluna `CNPJ`, com valores em ambos DFs. Caso seja igual, deve preencher em `df['codprojeto']` o valor de `df2['codprojeto']`.

Tentativa 1:

```py
for i in range(len(df['CNPJ'])):
    for j in range(len(df2['CNPJ'])):
        if df2.loc[j, 'CNPJ'] == df.loc[i, 'CNPJ']:
            df.loc[i, 'codprojeto'] ==  df2.loc[j, 'codprojeto']
```

Retorna:

```
Erro: KeyError: 4
```

Tentativa 2:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
    if str(row['CNPJ']) == row2['CNPJ']:
        df.loc[index,'codprojeto'] = df2.loc[index2,'codprojeto']
```

Retorna: execução eterna; processamento pendente.

Conjunto de dados (amostra):

DF:

```
CNPJ,DATA,codprojeto
00000000000123,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
99900000000123,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
00000000000123,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
00000000000123,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
00000000000145,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
00000000000123,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
00000000000167,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
00000000000167,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
00000000000167,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
00000000000167,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
00000000000101,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
00000000000122,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
00000000000144,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
00000000000123,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
00000000000155,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
00000000000155,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
00000000000155,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
00000000000166,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
99900000000123,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
99900000000123,2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC,0
```

DF2:

```
"codcliente";"nome";"CNPJ";"codprojeto"
1;"CLIENTE 1";"00000000000123";1234
2;"CLIENTE 1";"00000000000145";5678
3;"CLIENTE 1";"00000000000167";9012
4;"CLIENTE 1";"00000000000189";3456
5;"CLIENTE 1";"00000000000101";7890
6;"CLIENTE 1";"00000000000122";11
7;"CLIENTE 1";"00000000000133";22
8;"CLIENTE 1";"00000000000144";33
9;"CLIENTE 9";"00000000000155";44
10;"CLIENTE 10";"00000000000166";55
```

O DF e DF2 originais possuem, respectivamente, 635939 e 1054 linhas.

Para os casos que não houver CNPJ compatível, deixar como 0 o 'codprojeto' mesmo.

Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: Marlos, boa tarde! Consegue disponibilizar o conjunto de dados? Abraço!

Comment: Sem os dados é difícil responder, mas te adianto que 1) Essa solução é extremamente lenta, use `np.where` em vez de nested loops O(n^2); 2) Na última linha o correto é `=` e não `==`; 3) O erro possivelmente está ocorrendo pq 4 não está no index de `df` ou `df2`

Comment: Inclui o conjunto de dados na pergunta. Sobre o '==' na última linha, já fiz a correção. Sobre o KeyError 4, é estranho, pois não estou buscando por valor 4, e sim comparando entre 2 valores apartados.

Comment: Uma dica para conseguir sempre respostas objetivas e que te atendam é disbonibilizar amostras de dados que contemplem todos os problemas que você esta passando. Com os dados que você disbonibilizou você recebeu 2 respostas diferentes que apitaram 2 erros diferentes. Existe um tópico exclusivo que mostra como criar um [exemplo minimo, completo e verificavel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Tranquilo, obrigado pela dica, Terry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minha sugestão é fazer um LEFT JOIN usando a função `merge()`. E para ela funcionar corretamente não é necessário criar a coluna **codprojeto** com zeros no DataFrame 'DF'

```
# aqui vou excluir a coluna 'codprojeto' de df, 
# mas acredito que no seu projeto seja necessário 
# apenas comentar a linha onde ela é criada
df = df.drop(columns= ['codprojeto'])

df = df.merge(df2[['CNPJ', 'codprojeto']], on = 'CNPJ', how = 'left').fillna(0)
#para não ter valores duplicados use
#df = df.merge(df2[['CNPJ', 'codprojeto']].drop_duplicates('CNPJ'), on = 'CNPJ', how = 'left').fillna(0)

#para converter a nova coluna para int
df['codprojeto'] = df['codprojeto'].astype('int64')

#saida:
    CNPJ    DATA                    codprojeto
0   123     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 1234.0
1   999...  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 0.0
2   123     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 1234.0
3   123     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 1234.0
4   145     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 5678.0
5   123     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 1234.0
6   167     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 9012.0
7   167     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 9012.0
8   167     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 9012.0
9   167     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 9012.0
10  101     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 7890.0
11  122     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 11.0
12  144     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 33.0
13  123     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 1234.0
14  155     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 44.0
15  155     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 44.0
16  155     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 44.0
17  166     2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 55.0
18  999...  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 0.0
19  999...  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC 0.0
```

Comment: Mesma questão, Terry: coluna `codprojeto` em df fica zerada.

Comment: Acredito que o tipo das coluna CNPJ não é o mesmo em ambos os dataframes.  Tente converter essa coluna para número usando o comando : `df['CNPJ'] = df['CNPJ'].astype('int64')`. Faça o mesmo no df2 e depois faça o merge

Comment: Terry, aí acontece o erro:  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '00.000.000'

Comment: Pelo visto em um dos seus DataFrames o campo CNPJ possui pontos, o que é um problema para converter para o tipo numérico. Pesquise ou crie uma nova pergunta no SO-PT sobre como transformar números com pontos para int64 no pandas, dando exemplos e como deve ser a saida final

Comment: Terry, deu certo! Tinham três linhas de teste com '00.000.000'. Quando as removi, rodou. Porém, armazenou como float (inclusive no seu exemplo acima). Da pra converter pra int? Além disso, foram acrescentadas mais 14.773 linhas no dataframe, enquanto o esperado é manter os 636.042 registros.

Comment: se não tiver nenhum valor nulo da pra converter para int, desta forma: `df['codprojeto'] = df['codprojeto'].astype('int64')`

Comment: Sobre aumentar o número de linhas, entra o que eu comentei na resposta do @imonferrari, sugeri usar o `drop_duplicates` junto com o `map`e você disse que não poderia usa-lo porque cada CNPJ tinha informações únicas dentro do DF2

Comment: Editei minha resposta com os comandos mostrando como não ter dados duplicates e como converter para int a coluna `codprojeto`

Comment: Não entendi como usar o drop dentro do map. Poderia me explicar, por gentileza?

Comment: Eu coloquei um exemplo na minha resposta que evita a criação de linha extras, é só dar uma olhada no [update](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/484952/revisions)

Comment: Terry, deu certo! Era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Muitíssimo obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

Importando o pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

Carregando os arquivos de teste

```
df = pd.read_csv('./df.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('./df2.csv', sep = ';')
```

**df**

```
    CNPJ        DATA              codprojeto
0   123  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
1   123  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
2   123  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
3   123  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
4   145  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
5   123  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
6   167  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
7   167  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
8   167  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
9   167  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
10  101  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
11  122  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
12  144  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
13  123  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
14  155  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
15  155  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
16  155  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
17  166  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
18  123  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
19  123  2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC      0
```

**df2**

```
    codcliente  nome        CNPJ    codprojeto
0   1           CLIENTE 1   123     1234
1   2           CLIENTE 1   145     5678
2   3           CLIENTE 1   167     9012
3   4           CLIENTE 1   189     3456
4   5           CLIENTE 1   101     7890
5   6           CLIENTE 1   122       11
6   7           CLIENTE 1   133       22
7   8           CLIENTE 1   144       33
8   9           CLIENTE 9   155       44
9   10          CLIENTE 10  166       55
```

Mapeando a Serie de df para atribuir os valores à correspondência no df2

```
df['codprojeto'] = df['CNPJ'].map(df2.set_index('CNPJ')['codprojeto']).fillna(0)
```

Imprimindo

```
df
```

Saída:

```
    CNPJ             DATA           codprojeto
0   123   2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC   1234
1   123   2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC   1234
2   123   2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC   1234
3   123   2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC   1234
4   145   2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC   5678
5   123   2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC   1234
6   167   2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC   9012
7   167   2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC   9012
8   167   2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC   9012
9   167   2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC   9012
10  101   2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC   7890
11  122   2020-12-02 00:00:00 UTC     11
...
```

Comment: Parabéns pela solução. Você pode explicar o que a função map está fazendo nesse caso? Par mim não é óbvio

Comment: Segue, Imonferrari:

`df['codprojeto'] = df2['CNPJ_EMPRESA'].map(df.set_index('CNPJ_EMPRESA')['codprojeto']).fillna(0)` 

Retorna o seguinte: 

`InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: Rodou, mas preencheu a coluna "codprojeto" do df com "0.0", ao invés de inserir o "codprojeto" do df2.

Comment: É como se não encontrasse nada e preenchesse toda a coluna com 0, ao invés do valor presente em df2['codprojeto'].

Comment: Segue preenchendo a coluna 'codprojeto' com zeros... 


codprojeto
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0

Comment: [Veja](https://i.ibb.co/s97z9gD/pandas.png)

Comment: Sim, vejo que pra você funciona, mas aqui continua preenchendo com zeros. Será que é pelo falo de o CNPJ, no df estar como int64 e no df2 como object, se perdendo na hora de realizar o map? Ou seja, em um dataset é um número, no outro uma string.

Comment: É uma possibilidade, aqui eles ja são convertido em int64 pelo proprio pandas,. Você pode testar fazendo `df2['CNPJ'] = df2['CNPJ'].astype('int64')` na hora que carregar o data frame.

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '00.000.000'

Comment: Me envia seus 2 datasets inteiros. Hospeda eles no google drive e cola o link aqui.

Comment: Imon, são dados internos, não posso colocar publicamente. Tem alguma maneira de entrarmos em contato particularmente?

Comment: Enviei um e-mail.

Comment: Pela mensagem de erro me parece que usar um `df.drop_duplicates('CNPJ_EMPRESA')` antes de setar a coluna como index (dentro do `.map`) resolve, você consegue testar?

Comment: Terry, não posso dropar os CNPJs, pois cada linha possui informações únicas, por mais que o CNPJ se repita.