# Adicionar uma nova coluna em um Dataframe após comparar dados com outro Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho um dataframe ***df_moeda*** e preciso inserir nova coluna com base na comparação com outro dataframe ***df_cotacao***.

Abaixo tenho dataframe só com os nomes das moedas:

```
df_moeda=pd.DataFrame({"Moeda":["BTC", "ETH","WAVES","ADA"]})
```

Dataframe ***df_moeda***:

```
   Moeda
0    BTC
1    ETH
2  WAVES
3    ADA
```

Abaixo o dataframe com a cotação dos pares ***moeda-real***:

```
df_cotacao=pd.DataFrame({"Pares":["ETH-BRL", "ADA-BRL","BTC-BRL","WAVES-BRL"], "Cotação":["12", "34", "56", "78"]})
```

Dataframe ***df_cotacao***:

```
       Pares Cotação
0    ETH-BRL      12
1    ADA-BRL      34
2    BTC-BRL      56
3  WAVES-BRL      78
```

Como resultado, quero adicionar uma coluna no dataframe ***df_moeda*** inserindo a contação da moeda correspondente.

- Atenção: Os dois dataframes não estão com a mesma sequência das moedas.

O dataframe ***df_moeda*** deveria ficar assim:

```
   Moeda     Cotação
0    BTC          56
1    ETH          12
2  WAVES          78
3    ADA          34
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como preencher uma coluna de um DF Pandas usando, como comparação, uma coluna específica entre este e outro DF?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/484866/como-preencher-uma-coluna-de-um-df-pandas-usando-como-compara%c3%a7%c3%a3o-uma-coluna-es)

Comment: Cria uma coluna chamada moeda na base df_cotação com as primeiras 3 letras da coluna pares. Depois faz um merge com a base df_moeda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você quer fazer (pelo menos é o que parece) não precisa juntar dois data frames, pois o próprio data frame cotação já traz a informação que você quer.

```
df_cotacao['Moeda'] = df_cotacao['Pares'].apply(lambda x: x[:-4])
df_novo = df_cotacao.drop(columns= 'Pares')
df_novo[['Moeda','Cotação']]
```

1. Faz um slicing para obter os nomes
2. Remove a coluna
3. Ordena a apresentação das colunas(variáveis)

Saída:

```
    Moeda   Cotação
    ETH     12
    ADA     34
    BTC     56
    WAVES   78
```

Comment: Muito boa a solução. Eu usaria `.apply(lambda x: x.split("-")[0])` ao invés de `.apply(lambda x: x[:-4])`. Mas para o exemplo oferecido na pergunta ambas funcionam.

Comment: Fala Paulo, boa tarde! Essa opção que você propôs também é muito boa. Ontem numa pergunta do mesmo autor eu sugeri essas duas abordagens! Grande abraço!!

Comment: Obrigado pela solução, mas se df_moeda tivesse uma coluna com saldo de cada moeda, como seria a solução? Acredito que seria melhor adicionar uma nova coluna do df_moeda. Eu não elaborei muito bem a pergunta.

Comment: Consegui responder meu comentário anterior com a solução da [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/484866/como-preencher-uma-coluna-de-um-df-pandas-usando-como-compara%c3%a7%c3%a3o-uma-coluna-es?noredirect=1&lq=1) indicada pelo @lmonferrari Obrigado gente!!